# Merge several Columns of a Gridview based on their header values using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, merge

I have a gridview which looks something like [image: this].

I am trying to combine multiple columns in a gridview into a single column based on it’s header value.

I am trying to combine Street Name, City, State, Zipcode under one value of Address so that I get the value as a single column **Address**. That would reduce my total column number to just 3 in the above example with ID, Person and Address. How can I do that in C#?

I am not using BoundField/Template field instead, reading from excel file and loading it’s data and binding it into a gridview so I do not know how many columns I might have in each run. 
I saw many tutorials which focuses on Boundfield data and using DataBinder.Eval() Method to accomplish this but this does not work for me.

My gridview simply looks like this :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center"> </asp:GridView>
```

My code behind is basically using FileUpload Control to upload excel file, establishing OleDBConnection, Creating a new DataTable and binding everything into GridView1.

How then is it possible to get them under a single column using C#? Any idea/help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: The "..." values on the last and secondlast row of the gridview are other values. This is just to show there could be hundreds of values.

Answer (score 0):

> My code behind is basically using FileUpload Control to upload excel
>   file, establishing OleDBConnection, Creating a new DataTable and
>   binding everything into GridView1.

When you Create your Datatable add new column called Address, foreach Row in your Datatable populate the "Address" Column with the desired value (Using For example a String.concat(...)).

After that you can edit your asp code like below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
<columns>
    <!-- all the fields from the DT you want to show-->
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" Visible="true"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Person" Visible="true"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" Visible="true"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Other_Column_You_Like_in_dt" Visible="true"></asp:BoundField>
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.concat` method to concat 4 columns to 1 columns example :

```
ID:1 Adress:111 east st ; Loneville ;TX;77011
```

In this i have used `;` to spilt and you can replace them with other signal.And when you want to reqest data from this column use this code(That is only my idea):

```
string[] adress=person_datagrid.Rows[adress].Cells[number cell].Value.ToString().Split(';');
 string street_name=adress[0];
 string city=adress[1];
 string state=adress[2];
 string Zipcode=adress[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this: (untested). You may use StringBuilder to concatenate text and have check for nullorempty string

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[2];
     cell.Text = cell.Text + “ “ + e.Row.Cells[3] + “ “ + e.Row.Cells[4] + “ “ + e.Row.Cells[5];
    cell.ColumnSpan = 4;
    e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;
     e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false;
     e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = false;
}
}
```